# Android Keyboard Source

Tags: android, android-source

Is the source available for the default Android Keyboard?

Answer (score 17):

have a look at this: [inputmethods/LatinIME.git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/)

Comment: the link is outdated http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME.git;a=tree

Answer (score 6):

The current link to the Keyboard Source Code of Android can be found here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/

Comment: `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME` will be helpful to keep track of things, I suppose. And do some greppery on your own box.